# Selecting a range of files in a directory, Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting

I have a function which lists files under a given path

```
public static String[] listFiles(String path)
```

the files are named course_1 -to- course_15.

I want to implement some functionality which allows me to only select files in a given range:

```
public static String[] listFiles(String path, int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

where the int's passed as arguments correspond to the 1 - 15.

eg.

if the startIndex = 9, and the endIndex = 11, then only select:

course_9
course_10
course_11

Is there any way to implement this whihout making the function relatively complex? Also there are no file extensions used.

**Edit:**
I should also mention that the path is the root directory of where the files exist:

```
for(String content:localDirectory.list()){
    if(content!=null){
        File contentFile= new File(path + "/" + content);                   

        if(!contentFile.isDirectory()){
            files.add(contentFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}

if (files.size()==0)
    return null;
} else{ 
    return files.toArray(new String[files.size()]);

}
```

where files is an ArrayList initalised inside the method

Comment: Look at [FileNameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [File reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29):

> `public File[] listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)`
>
> Returns an array of
>   abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory
>   denoted by this abstract pathname that satisfy the specified filter.
>   The behavior of this method is the same as that of the `listFiles()`
>   method, except that the pathnames in the returned array must satisfy
>   the filter. If the given filter is null then all pathnames are
>   accepted. Otherwise, a pathname satisfies the filter if and only if
>   the value true results when the `FilenameFilter.accept(File, String)`
>   method of the filter is invoked on this abstract pathname and the name
>   of a file or directory in the directory that it denotes.

I believe this one suits your needs.

**EDIT:**
If the above does not help, see

> `public String[] list(FilenameFilter filter)`
>
> Returns an array of strings naming the files and directories in the
>   directory denoted by this abstract pathname that satisfy the specified
>   filter. The behavior of this method is  the same as that of the
>   `list()` method, except that the strings in the returned array must 
>   satisfy the filter. If the given filter is null then all names are
>   accepted. Otherwise, a  name satisfies the filter if and only if the
>   value true results when the  `FilenameFilter.accept(File, String)`
>   method of the filter is invoked on this abstract pathname and the name
>   of a file or directory in the directory that it denotes.

as per Nathan Hughes comment.

Comment: +1 for this, but i think File.list(FilenameFilter) would better match what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea, implemented using [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/List.html). Note that this function only generates all the possible file names, without checking if these files actually exist.

```
public static String[] listFiles(String path, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    // create an dynamically growing list to store the resulting file names
    List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // iterate from startIndex to endIndex inclusive
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
        // construct the desired file name
        String name = path + "_" + i;
        // and add it to the List
        namesList.add(name);
    }
    // convert the List to an array and return the array
    return namesList.toArray();
}
```

Additional notes:

- Take a look at the [tutorial about Java Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) to understand how `List` and `ArrayList` work.
- If this is an exercise about arrays and not production code, you have to reimplement your function to only use arrays.

Comment: How are you going to call your `listFiles` method? What values will the `path` parameter have?

Comment: Its a String read from a file, and is the parent directory of where the files are kept. inside the method i use  `File localDirectory= new File( path );`

Comment: Does your method look for all file names ending with (e.g.) `_9` to `_11`? Is the file name prefix `"course"` hard coded?

Comment: `course` is not hard coded, but the expected suffix will always be `"_n"`

Comment: Then you need a parameter to specify the prefix ("`course`"). Otherwise, if the directory contains both `course_9`...`course_11` and `foo_9`...`foo_11`, your method will list `foo_*` too.